# Polar movement towards cursor sfml and c++

Tags: c++, game-design, sprites, movement, sfml

I got smooth movement down moving based on the window but I wanted to see if I could move my sprite to my cursor when I pressed w instead of just in the -y direction but everything went wrong right away. Here is the function I'm trying to make work:

```
    void Ship::MoveShip(float ShipAccel, float deltaTime)
{
    float movementY;
    float movementX;
    m_ShipVel += ShipAccel * deltaTime;
    if (m_ShipVel > m_ShipMaxVel)
    {
        m_ShipVel = m_ShipMaxVel;
    }
    else if (m_ShipVel < -m_ShipMaxVel)
    {
        m_ShipVel = -m_ShipMaxVel;
    }
    movementX = m_ShipVel * (cos(m_ShipAngle * 180 / PI));
    movementY = m_ShipVel * (sin(m_ShipAngle * 180 / PI));

    m_SpriteShip.move(movementX, movementY);
}
```

Just made a video of what's happening with this code: [Video](https://youtu.be/DHpbuztcwd4)

Answer (score 1):

I had the reciprocal of what I should have been using. The math.h class's sin and cos function want the arguments in radians and m_ShipAngle is in Degrees. I was doing

```
   movementX = m_ShipVel * (cos(m_ShipAngle * 180 / PI));
   movementY = m_ShipVel * (sin(m_ShipAngle * 180 / PI));
```

When I should have been doing:

```
  movementX = m_ShipVel * (cos(m_ShipAngle * PI / 180));
  movementY = m_ShipVel * (sin(m_ShipAngle * PI / 180));
```

Sorry everyone who's time I wasted! I should have thought little harder.